# How do I remove a custom MIUI lockscreen via adb or other means?

Tags: lock-screens, customization, miui

So I downloaded a lockscreen for MIUI from the themes app but apparently it doesn't go well with my phone and it just displays the wallpaper without the actual lockscreen. The problem is, now, I can't unlock the phone as there is nothing to drag on the screen. My phone is also secured by a pattern. How do I remove this problematic custom lockscreen and revert to the stock one?

Obviously I'd either have to do it via ADB or something. Can anyone help me out? I can restart the phone and all but that's really all I can do since everything else is behind the lockscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Fist you need to know MIUI package name

```
adb shell pm list package -3
```

This command will display all the third party installed apps. If MIUI lockscreen does not show up here use :

```
adb shell pm list package -s
```

OR

```
adb shell pm list package -f
```

then copy the package name and use this command :

```
adb shell pm uninstall <your app package>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the answer was, actually simpler than I thought. As it turns out, MIUI has a built in fallback for these kinds of problems. The solution is to press <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> + <kbd>Back Button</kbd> and it should do unlock the phone for you. I found this out by posting this same question on the MIUI forums.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the solution by Propeller, I would tell the method to do that by ADB (just for knowledge say)...

MIUI lockscreen is the ROM's built in lockscreen which you really dont want to uninstall. Simply removing the theme would do the job.

- Boot your phone to recovery by pressing and holding **volume up + power button** (going into recovery isnt necessary. But recommended if you haven't enabled *USB Debugging* or didn't yet add that PC's *RSA Fingerprint* to phone in which case ADB wont work if your phone is Powered On. Otherwise there's no need to go into recovery).
- Connect your phone to PC and run these commands for ADB:

`adb shell
mount -o rw,remount /data
cp /data/system/theme/lockscreen /sdcard/
rm -r /data/system/theme/lockscreen
reboot`

**Or**

If you have a recovery with built in terminal emulator such as TWRP, you dont even need to use ADB. Just boot your phone to recovery and go to `Mounts` in recovery and make sure `/data` is selected.

Then open terminal emulator inside your recovery and run these commands->

`cp /data/system/theme/lockscreen /sdcard/
rm -r /data/system/theme/lockscreen
reboot`

Both these methods will backup your lockscreen theme to sdcard and also remove it from system and your default lockscreen would be used at next restart.